# Click On Notification Download Completion It Opens downloaded all files of particular folder

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In following code, When Download completed and User click on notification then it directly goes to File Manager and open "My Application" Folder

In Folder Image files, PDF as well as excel,word or zip file is there.

Folder path is : /storage/emulated/0/My Application

My Code is :

ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Bar Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        build.setProgress(100, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(ID, build.build());
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Downloading file in background thread
     * */
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        int count;
        try {
            String NoticeUrl = "http://" + DOMAIN +"//NoticeBoard/";
            System.out.println("============ Notice : =============" + NoticeUrl);
            Log.d("file name exec", f_url[0] + "");
            URL url =  new URL( NoticeUrl
                    + Uri.encode(f_url[0].trim()));

            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // getting file length
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);
            direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/My Application");

            if(!direct.exists()) {
                if(direct.mkdir()); //directory is created;
            }
            // Output stream to write file
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(
                direct + "/"  + f_url[0].trim());

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));

                // writing data to file
                output.write(data, 0, count);

            }

            // flushing output
            output.flush();

            // closing streams
            output.close();
            input.close();

            // Displaying downloaded image into image view
            // Reading image path from sdcard
            FilePath = direct + "/"  + f_url[0].trim();

            // setting downloaded into image view
            //my_image.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(imagePath));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        }
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i <= 100; i += 5) {
            // Sets the progress indicator completion percentage
            publishProgress(String.valueOf(Math.min(i, 100)));
            try {
                // Sleep for 5 seconds
                Thread.sleep(2 * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.d("Failure", "sleeping failure");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Updating progress bar
     * */
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
        // setting progress percentage
        pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        build.setProgress(100, Integer.parseInt(progress[0]), false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(ID, build.build());
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String f_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(activity, "File Downloaded at : - " + FilePath , 4600).show();
        System.out.println("==================" + FilePath);
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Download Completed", 200).show();
    //  build.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        /*File file = new File(FilePath);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(activity.getApplication(), 0, intent, 0);
        build.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        build.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));*/
        build.setContentText("Download complete");

        build.setProgress(0, 0, false);

        mNotifyManager.notify(ID, build.build());
        //Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse(FilePath); // a directory
        //intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
        //activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));

    }

}
```

Comment: Please be specific what do you want?

Comment: I need all the files of this folder which are available in this folder

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? If your question is "how do I do this?", please explain what you tried and what specific problems you encountered. You can use Java file I/O, via the `File` class, to list the files in a given directory.

Comment: I updated my question with code, can you please tell about it to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set an Activity which will be opened on the `notification` click and then you need a `ListView` to show the desired files in your `ListView`.

the following code may help you. It helps you to view the files in listview and

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

myList = new ArrayList<String>();   

String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
file = new File( root_sd + "/external_sd" ) ;       
File list[] = file.listFiles();

for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
{
    myList.add( list[i].getName() );
}

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList ));

}
```

implement onClick method as per your implementation of what you want to do.

i hope it helps.

Comment: I updated my Question with Code which is already Done by me can you please help me out on the base of my code?

Comment: basically you dont want download manager to open. You want to show your own activity with the list of files? am i right?

Comment: yes, I dont want to saw files in listview , I Only want to go to that place where my file is store after downloading